# How to force focus on android edit text

Tags: android

I have a trouble with Android Layout Development.
Here is Process
-Load data from Text to Android ListView.
-Set Request Focus on EditText.

How can set focus on EditText when loading on ListView completely by programmatically changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,in your class, set this programtically it may help you :-

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Thank for your help, Ms Tiwari, I knew that method, however I think that after data were loaded in ListView, although I call editText.requestFocus(), cursor not focus on edit text. Do you have any solutions.